# Tkinter self.grid making widgets invisible

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am making a username/password confirmation using tkinter, and I've run into a problem where the widgets are no longer showing.

```
"""
Password entry/confirmation class
"""
from tkinter import *

class Menu:
    def __init__(self,master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        title_username = Label(master, text="User Name")
        title_username.grid(row=0, column=0)

        title_password = Label(master, text="Password")
        title_password.grid(row=1, column=0)

        global username
        username = Entry(master, bd=5)
        username.grid(row=0, column=1)

        global password
        password = Entry(master, bd=5)
        password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        confirm_username = Button(master, text="Done",
                                  fg="black",command=self.get_username)
        confirm_username.grid(row=0, column=2)

        confirm_password = Button(master, text="Done",
                                  fg="black",command=self.get_password)
        confirm_password.grid(row=1, column=2)

    def show_all(self):
        self.root.update()
        self.root.deiconify()

    def get_username(self):
        global username
        username = username.get()
        print(username)

    def get_password(self):
        global password
        password = password.get()
        print(password)

root = Tk()
app = Menu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The widgets have not been showing since I've been using `grid()` instead of `pack()`. 
(global needs to be declared twice on each variable for some reason, but this is not an issue)

Comment: Yes, it needs more (the "C" in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: "I've been using `grid` instead of `pack`" does that mean that you've used `pack` elsewhere in the same window? You can only use one window manager per surface.

Comment: I mean, I switched it out from pack to grid. I'll quickly grab the body of the code

Comment: Using multiple geometry managers would result in a crash/error message, and the question makes it sound like the app runs but doesn't display the widgets.

Comment: Correct, it runs but just doesn't display anything.

Comment: Ran it, it crashed due to using two geometry managers. I removed `frame = Frame(master)` and `frame.pack()`, ran it again, and it gave me a pretty little GUI with widgets and all.

Comment: I would recommend changing `password` to `Entry(master, bd=5, show='*')` so that it displays asterisks instead of the password. You can alternatively use a zero-width non-joiner (Unicode 200C) to have it display nothing at all. Also, don't name your app class `Menu` - that's already in use by `tkinter`, so your class is currently masking that (i.e., you won't be able to add a menu to your program).

Comment: As far as using `frame.grid()`, there's no point to having that `Frame` there at all, as it contains no widgets. However, since I couldn't reproduce the described behavior, I suspect that there's more to this program, so the `Frame` may end up doing something somewhere.

Comment: Note that the function show_all references self.root which does not exist.

Comment: We'll debug that bridge when we call it. :)

Comment: show_all was my attempt at fixing the issue, it won't be used. Thanks again

Comment: "We'll debug that bridge when we call it"  I'll use that one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the initial frame (variable `frame`) in `master`, and you are using `pack`. The remaining widgets are also going in `master`, and you are using `grid`. This typically results in your program locking up because grid will try to arrange the widgets, pack will notice they've changed and try to rearrange the widgets, grid will notice they've changed and try to rearrange the widgets, and so on.

My guess is, the original intent of the code was to put `title_username`, `title_password`, etc. in `frame` rather than `master` since there's no other apparent use for `frame`.